# AngularJS Bootstrap UI, issues passing data into modal. selectedCards undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a feeling I am very much confused about the $scope, and am therefore selecting nothing. Having a hard time understanding where selectedCard is being called from, if at all.
Would anyone mind explaining to me where I am going wrong?

NOTE:
I believe I have too many files etc to create a plunkr worth looking through, but a live version of the site can be found here:
http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/card_site/index.html

Javascript:

```
angular.module("cardSite", ['masonry', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService, $scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    $scope.cards = [];
    dataService.getCards().then(function(response) {
        $scope.cards = response.data;
    }, function() {});
    $scope.plusOne = function(card) {
        card.card_rating += 1;
    };
    $scope.isActive = false;
    $scope.changeClass = function() {
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
    };
    // Modal stuff here
    $scope.modalUpdate = function(size, selectedCard) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'sendCard.html',
            controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, cards) {

                $scope.cards = cards;


                $scope.send = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selectedCard);
                    console.log($scope.selectedCard);
                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };

            },
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                cards: function() {
                    return $scope.selectedCard;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedCard) {
            $scope.selected = selectedCard;
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };


});
```

sendCard.html:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Ready to send a card?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Card selected: <b>{{card.card_title}}</b>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

HTML for calling the modal:

```
<button ng-click="modalUpdate(lg, card)" class="btn btn-stretch">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the:

```
ng-controller="mainCtrl"
```

In your sendCard.html file

Comment: Didn't do anything sadly!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use

```
$scope.selectedCard
```

You can just use selectedCard, since it's not tied to the $scope anyway:

```
resolve: {
    cards: function() {
         return selectedCard;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have `selectedCard` set on your main controller's scope; you are just passing in whichever card is clicked as the `selectedCard`. Thus, all you have to do is resolve the card the user has clicked:

```
resolve: {
  card: function() {
     return selectedCard;
  }
}
```

...And pass in `card` to your modal controller function. Then, assuming your `selectedCard` has the property you show in your template (`card_title`), everything should render as you expect.

EDIT: The above will work for you, but also just noticed that you have the plural `$scope.cards` in your modal controller and singular `card` in your template. You might consider changing everything to the singular, since it matches your data object. It's also hard to tell if your `sendCard.html` is in a separate file (or is an ng-template script), but as @eliagentili said, you should remove the ng-controller attribute from it.

Finally, you'll need to fix your `send` function:

```
$scope.send = function() {
  $uibModalInstance.close($scope.card);
  console.log($scope.card);
};
```